# Is there a way to invert a CSS custom property value? E. g. 15px -> -15px

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a var like this:

```
--size-sm: 15px;
```

And want to use it for a negative margin.

```
        a:first-child {
          margin-left: var(--size-sm);
        }
```

Is there any way how the value could be inverted? I tried few syntax like `margin-left: -var(--size-sm);` and `margin-left: -(--size-sm);` without success.

Comment: Does `calc(-1 * var(--size-sm))` work?

Comment: Yes it works, how didn't I think of this :). As marked by BoltClock, there's an extensive explanation in the question that's already been answered. Sorry for the duplicate.